# Why does this SVG to ICO conversion with ImageMagick batch script I wrote produce broken images?

Tags: bash, image, image-processing, imagemagick, ico

Okay I've been doing a bunch of searching on this topic and I can't seem to find a good answer on this website, so please read this entire thing before marking it as a duplicate or whatever.

I'm writing some personal zsh utilities to make it easy for me to batch process icons into various different formats.

Here's the version output info for the imagemagick convert utility

```
┌─  ~/LinuxSVGsets/Dex_KDE/actions                                                                                          
└─➤ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

Here is my current script

```
function svg2icoBatch ()  {
for fname in $1/**/*.svg
do

#take off the svg
pathAndName=${fname%.svg}

#take off the path from the file name
iconname=${pathAndName##*/}

#take off the file name from the path
iconpath=$pathAndName:h

#create new folder for converted icons to be placed in
mkdir -p ${iconpath}/ico-converted/

 convert $fname -background none -density 256 -define icon:auto-resize=16,32,48,64,256 ${iconpath}/ico-converted/${iconname}.ico
echo "\033[1;33m converted ${iconname}.svg to ico\n \033[0m"
done

}
```

the resulting ico looks like garbage:

[image]

When I try opening them up on an online ico viewer to make sure this wasn't just something weird with the image previewer utility in Ubuntu, I see a super blurry version of the icon that doesn't include it's additional sizes. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here. 
[image]

Any clues?

Comment: You're providing `convert` with an output filename, but no input filename. Perhaps you meant to do `convert $fname -background transparent -density 256x256 ${iconpath}/ico-converted/${iconname}.ico`?

Comment: @MikeHolt Maybe I'm misunderstanding how convert works but the input filename should be covered by $fname. It's a for loop that goes through all folders and subfoldres using the $1/**/*.svg glob pattern. Echo $fname gives the correct output.

Comment: The code you posted isn't passing `$fname` to `convert`.

Comment: Oh whoops. I overlooked that. My png2ico script doesn't work either though and it does include $fname. I tried the svg2ico and posted about it because it seemed simpler than my original attempt for the png2ico. png2ico function is as follows: `convert -background transparent ${fname} -define icon:auto-resize=16,24,32,48,64,72,96,128,256 "${iconpath}/converted/${iconname}.ico"`

I'll go ahead and fix the svg2ico and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Are you getting the same error message (no images defined) in your png2ico script?

Comment: yes. Example is `convert-im6.q16: unable to open image `./16/converted/converted/format-border-set-diagonal-tl-br.ico': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.`

When I add fname to svg2ico it works but only after I manually create ico-converted. the node module I used previously just auto created the new folders but I guess I'm going to have to write something into my function so that it creates the folder itself.

Comment: Are you sure the *directory* `./16/converted/converted` exists? The `convert` command will most likely not create the directory for you, and this may be what it's complaining about. Also, I see that there are two instances of `converted` in your path (as shown in the error message). Perhaps your `$iconpath` variable doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: Ah yeah the problem was that there wasn't a folder. I've fixed that. Though the resulting ico files look like a total mess. I'll update my main post with pictures.

Comment: I would suggest posting a new question instead of continually updating your post with new problems. And as always, try to reduce your questions to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You'll get more people willing to help if your questions are short and sweet and to the point.

Comment: Sure thing, will do. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Also is it possible for me to just rewrite my question? I'm a little worried about making a new question. I haven't used SO in about a year because last time I kept getting messages saying that I would be kicked off if I kept asking questions that were get 0 upvotes so I'm worried that if I post another time it will block me.

Comment: That's the first I've heard of that. I guess if you're constantly spamming low quality questions, the site moderators might take exception, but if you have a legitimate question I don't see the harm in asking. I suspect the mods would frown more on a constantly morphing question than multiple related questions. But I really can't say for sure what the site's policy is on that.

Comment: I certainly don't mean to be spamming questions. And while this above question did morph, I did try my best to add as much initial information as possible. Anyway I think I may have figured out the issue.

Comment: To be clear, I was speaking in hypotheticals, not accusing you of spamming. And I'm glad you figured out your issue.